# How to change a date format in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to convert a character varying date field to the format YYYYMMDD and below is the select query I tried. The output format is 1999-04-27 (YYYY-MM-DD). Admindate is the field name in the table.

```
select to_date( admindate,'MMDDYYYY')  from test;
```

Can someone please advice what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is admindate of type varchar? If so, In what format is the date stored?

Comment: Yes, Admindate is a varchar and it is srored as MMDDYYYY.

Comment: Oops, Sorry for the wrong question. I am trying the change the format to YYYYMMDD.

Comment: The real question is: why on earth are you storing a `date` in a `varchar` column? You should fix that as soon as possible

Answer (score 7):

Use `to_char` to convert the converted date into the desired format.

```
select to_char(to_date(admindate, 'MMDDYYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD')
from test;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW() :: DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation to your answer